# VOIP Business setup with asterisk

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk

Hi Asterisk and VOIP Expert,

I want to setup a new VOIP business using asterisk. The requirement is as below:

```
Asterisk Server 1----------|
| My central
Asterisk Server 2----------| ----SIP Call Forward---> [Asterisk Server]--Trunk-->Call route to any Number
| Billing and Charging
Asterisk Server 3----------| +
CRM
```

can any one guide how to use my central asterisk server from other asterisk server and route to other part of the word. I mean call establish to any phone. For the call establish to out world..what SIP need to use? Or i need to install digisum cards on my central asterisk server or what?

Target is 20,000 Concurrent call. How concurrent call Asterisk 11.4 can handle?

Please cooperate for any information, or any link or diagram.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup extension for each of your servers on central server.

After that you have use extension username/secret for trunk settings on other servers.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Connect+2+servers

Unfortunately asterisk not able handle 20000 calls. Hi load servers(more then 200 calls) have be setup by experts, if more then 400 call - using other technologies like opensips(ser,kamailio)+rtprpoxy.

About asterisk hiload: fine tuned asterisk can handle 400-700 calls with media

Without media(just setups,media go directly) asterisk can handle 20-30cps on hi-end servers like 3.2Ghz 8-core xeons:

-- upto 4500 calls with ASR 50% and ACD 5minutes or less if ASR/ACD go down)

-- upto 1250 calls with typical ASR 25% and ACD 2 minutes.

-- only 20-30 calls when no success,so such setup can't be considered production worth.

Note, setup without media WILL have issues if both legs not trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to forward your outside calls to a VoIP provider (using SIP), so them can be routed to any number worldwide.

Take a look at http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/VOIP+Service+Providers

Digium cards, as interface cards of any other manufacturer (Sangoma, for example), could be used to connect your asterisk box to a digital or analog interface of a telecom. Which allows you to receive and send calls over.

First way is less expensive, but much unreliable. Second gives you solid business solution, but charges rise significantly when you start making long-distance calls.